# Struggling with Shared Preferences and Lists

Tags: java, android

I'm busy with a very basic Note Taking Android App and having trouble with shared preferences.

In MainActivity is(should be) a list of the notes that were previously taken. To make a note you press menu and select make a note, that will take you to the second activity(writeANote.java).From there you make your note press menu and select add note, the it should be in in the listView(noteList). But its not... i think my problem is in MainActivity where I try to get the ArrayList from shared preferences.

I also have the ObjectSerializer class.

Please help.

Here is my code for the MainActivity.

```
package com.example.makeanote;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    static SharedPreferences sp;
    static ListView noteList;
    //static ArrayList<String> noteArray;
    //static ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    static ArrayAdapter<String> spListAdapter;
    ArrayList<String> newSpList;


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater menuInflater=getMenuInflater();
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu,menu);

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        switch(item.getItemId()){
            case(R.id.makeNewNote):
                Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),writeANote.class);
                startActivity(i);
                Log.i("SELECTED","make New Note");
                return true;
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        noteList=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.noteList);
        //noteArray= new ArrayList<String>();
        //adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,noteArray);
        try {
            newSpList=(ArrayList<String>)ObjectSerializer.deserialize((sp.getString("spList",ObjectSerializer.serialize(new ArrayList<String>()))));
            Log.i("new SP List", newSpList.get(0));
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        spListAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,newSpList);
        sp= (SharedPreferences) getSharedPreferences("com.example.makeanote", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);


        //String test=sp.getString("test","nothing");

        newSpList.add("test");
        //noteArray.add(test);
        if (newSpList.size()!=0) {
            noteList.setAdapter(spListAdapter);
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(this, "No Notes So Far", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
}
```

Here is my code for the second activity(writeANote.java).

```
package com.example.makeanote;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.EditText;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import static com.example.makeanote.MainActivity.sp;

public class writeANote extends AppCompatActivity {


    EditText note;
    ArrayList<String> spList;

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater menuInflater=getMenuInflater();
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_2,menu);

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        switch(item.getItemId()){
            case(R.id.addNote):
                //sp.edit().putString("test",).apply();
                spList.add(note.getText().toString());
                try {
                    MainActivity.sp.edit().putString("spList",ObjectSerializer.serialize(spList)).apply();
                }catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);

                Log.i("SELECTED","add New Note");
                return true;
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_write_a_note);

        spList=new ArrayList<>();

        note=findViewById(R.id.note);

    }
}
```

Comment: On which Activity the list is not visible?

Comment: In the MainActivity, when I log out in writeANote.java it logs the newly added note but it never renders in the listView itsels(noteList)

Comment: so I assume it goes into shared preferences but never comes out

Comment: No, actually the thing is you are adding a new list corresponding to the same key i.e. spList. You need to fetch the list from SharedPreference, then add object to the existing list present in SharedPreference.

Comment: Debug and check whether data exists or not. After debugging , if you still have problem , you can edit the question here.